# Need Script to run on Multiple Sheets on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

We have this script which will clear all grey cells. We have set it to run everyday. However with this script it will only clear the "Top Airway" Sheet. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add extra sheets to the list (dont know how to write code properly) or simply apply the code to all sheets in the file.

```
   function clearOrange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Top Airway');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] === '#efefef') {
        range.getCell(i+1,j+1).clearContent();
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: You might want to reformat the description to say exactly what your question is. ex: "How do you get all sheets in a file?"

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to 'get' all the sheets of the spreadsheet object and then loop through the returned sheets array.

See if this works

```
function clearGreyCells() {
var r, bg;
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
    .forEach(function (s) {
        r = s.getDataRange();
        bg = r.getBackgrounds();
        r.setValues(r.getValues()
            .map(function (b, i) {
                return b.map(function (c, j) {
                    return (bg[i][j] == '#efefef') ? null : c;
                })
            }))
        })
}
```